# Unable to install dependencies for package kableExtra

Tags: r, libxml2, rvest, xml2

I recently upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and started having problems concerning `rvest` and `xml2` in my R installation.
I'm trying to install package `kableExtra` but i keep getting errors even though  I have dependencies installed. `install.packages("kableExtra")` spits this:

[image]

Searching SO it came to my knowledge that I need dependencies `libxml2-dev` for xml2. What happens is that I already have it installed.

[image]

Some other important packages like `tidyverse` complains about those same dependencies. I usually solve things like this searching here and google, but this time it is not working. I need some serious help here.

I'll appreciate any tip.

Comment: You can do `sudo apt install r-cran-xml2` which gets you half-way there.

Comment: This certainly did solve. Thank you.

Comment: There is more -- you can get R from CRAN, and the same README mentions the c2d4u PPA with over 3000 binary packages:  https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html -- this also gets discussed hre in a few questions.

Comment: I really feel ashamed for not reading through this page before asking. I am certain i came across it minutes before.
I even added the ppa to my sources but idk why stopped in the middle. Living and learning. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this page with issues installing kableExtra on Ubuntu 20.04.  [This post helped](https://community.rstudio.com/t/problem-to-install-kableextra-on-ubuntu-20/101657).

```
sudo apt install libfontconfig1-dev
```